# Q: Should there be a Quora like feature to invite users to answer questions?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

On Quora, when a users asks a questions they are shown a list of suggested other users whom they can invite to answer the question. I am guessing the list is compiled by keywords and past (upvoted) answers from users who have shown expertise in that field.

It seems to me that there is no such feature on SO even though it might be very helpful in getting good answers faster and it would make it easier to find questions from ones personal area of expertise.

Comment: No. There shouldn't be. Our high rep users really don't want or need to be bombarded by "plz answer this" requests (whether relevant to their expertise or not).

Comment: _"even though it might be very helpful in getting good answers faster"_ Number one way to get good answers faster: Ask good, well-written, on-topic questions providing as much relevant information as you can. Trust me, this technique has worked for me so far. :)

Comment: @Kendra Really, because in my experiences asking a question that can trivially be answered in a few sentences with a few seconds through a google search is far more likely to be answered quickly than an actual quality question.

Comment: @Servy I wouldn't know, I tend to answer those without asking. I suppose I really should try that one some time to compare.

Comment: *"providing as much **relevant** information"* emphasis on **relevant**. so many post essays to describe a problem containing mostly irrelevant background story.

Comment: Or bounties.  That's a pretty big invitation.

Comment: no, please don't ever let that become a thing...

Comment: @ryanyuyu But that's a 2 day minimum.  It's not exactly the best way to get a question answered *quickly*.  It's a good way to get better answers, or get an answer *slowly* on a question that possibly wouldn't have gotten one at all otherwise.

Comment: @Patrice Which comment are you referring to?  You don't want bounties to become a thing ;p

Comment: @Servy ah, I didn't notice the "get the answer faster" part of the question.  You are completely right.

Comment: @Servy NO BOUNTIES! NO MORE. Nah, I was talking about the generic FR of the question :P

Answer (score 3):

In general, I don't think this is needed.

Users (answerers) can already follow tags to get relevant questions. The homepage also suggests questions using similar criteria. Adding a feature like this would just bombard the inboxes of the people who are already devoting a great deal of time to answering questions.

For the other side of this, which is bringing attention to neglected questions, as @ryanyuyu [said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314108/q-should-there-be-a-quora-like-feature-to-invite-users-to-answer-questions#comment290999_314108), we have bounties. Bounties let you bring attention to neglected questions with the broadest reach, and the best chance of finding someone who has your answer.

Comment: [Servy's observation that bounties don't help get answers _quickly_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314108/q-should-there-be-a-quora-like-feature-to-invite-users-to-answer-questions?noredirect=1#comment291004_314108Z)

Comment: @ryanyuyu: True. On the other hand, I don't think there's anything we can do to encourage quick answers, except having more users see the question, which as far as I can tell, is much better accomplished by the existing systems.